# Proyecto war con HTML5 + JSF Passthrough elements No funciona en JBoss EAP 7.1

Tags: html5, jsf, java-ee, jboss-eap, red-hat

He decidido realizar un proyecto web de forma que su diseño sea "lo más HTML5" posible pero que su "controlador" sea "lo más java" posible. Normalmente uso JSF + PrimeFaces, pero quiero hacer un cambio para no depender de librerias para faces. En la busqueda he encontrado proyectos que usan Passthrough Elements 
https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2014/10/30/jsf2html5-passthrough/
https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/enterprise-html5.html

El problema es el siguiente, he creado un proyecto dummy que corre en WildFly 17.0.1 con la siguiente configuración

**Archivo POM**

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>
            <version.jboss.bom>8.2.1.Final</version.jboss.bom>
            <version.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
            <version.surefire.plugin>2.16</version.surefire.plugin>
            <version.war.plugin>2.5</version.war.plugin>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        </properties>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
                <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es_CO" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">
<head jsf:id="head">
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body jsf:id="body">
    <input type="email" jsf:id="email" name="email" value="#{testBean.value}" required="required"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**TestBean.java**

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TestBean {
    private String value;
    public TestBean() {
        this.value= "uncorreo@dominio.com";
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Hasta aquí el proyecto compila, se despliega y funcional de forma correctasobre el servidor WildFly, sinembargo el proyecto se va a realizar sobre un servidor Jboss EAP 7.1 por lo cual he modificado las dependencias en el archivo pom.xml por las dependencias del servidor JBoss

**Archivo POM para JBoss EAP**

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>2.0.1.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>
    <version.jboss.bom>7.1.6.GA</version.jboss.bom>
    <version.compiler.plugin>3.8.1</version.compiler.plugin>
    <version.surefire.plugin>3.0.0-M3</version.surefire.plugin>
    <version.war.plugin>3.2.3</version.war.plugin>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-eap-javaee7-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.eap</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom}-redhat-00002</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Pero aqui cuando lo despliego en el servidor ya no funciona y cargo la pagina, en el elemento `input` del `index.xhtml` se cargar el texto `#{testBean.value}` y no "`uncorreo@dominio.com`" como sí se muestra en el servidor WildFly. Agradezco de su ayuda para poder determinar el error.

**Nota:** De acuerdo a la especificación de `jsf`, Passthrough esta disponible desde la versión 2.2, el servidor JBoss EAP 7.1 implementa la especificación jboss-`jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.13.redhat-1`

Answer (score 0):

Después de investigar un tiempo averigue que estas caracteristicas efectivamente estan desde JSF 2.2 sin embargo no estan soportadas por el servidor JBOS EAP 7.1. Estas caracteristicas se encuentran soportadas desde la versión 7.2 del Jboss EAP y se usan con la especificación 2.3 de JSF.

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-eap-javaee8</artifactId>
      <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
    
<dependencies>
  <!-- Dependencias JSF -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```